# Why the norm in the definition of differentiability?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

A function $f: \Bbb R^m \to \Bbb R^n$ is differentiable  at $x_0$ iff $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\|f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)-J(h)\|_{\Bbb R^n}}{\|h\|_{\Bbb R^m}}=0$$

Is there any particular reason we use the norm in the numerator here?  Isn't this equivalent to

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)-J(h)}{\|h\|_{\Bbb R^m}}=0?$$

Comment: how do you define $\lim_{k\to\infty} v_k=v$ when $(v_k)_k\subset\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: Component-wise I'd expect?  But I take your meaning.  Some of the tools for evaluating limits (like the sequential criterion) may be lost if we don't use scalars.

Comment: The idea of taking a limit is figuring out what the thing you are taking the limit of is getting "close" to.  So the sequence $1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, \dots$ is getting closer and closer to $0$, and $0$ is the only thing it is getting close to.  We use the norms because when you take the difference of two things in a norm, i.e., $|a - b|$, this can be interpreted as the "distance" between $a$ and $b$ in some sense.  Different norms give different ideas of distance, but they can all be interpreted as distance.

Comment: So it makes sense to have the norm in the definition of this limit, because the idea of a limit is something getting "close" to something else.

Comment: It is more than that, indeed, as Omno[...]mno said, asking for it to be component-wise is the same as asking for the for the norm to go to $0$. I recommend you to try to show the following:
$$\lim_{k\to \infty} v_k=0 \qquad \iff \qquad \lim_{k\to\infty}\|v_k\|=0$$
to get more intuition on the question.

Comment: @user46944 Note that all norms are equivalent in finite dimensional spaces. And in infinite dimensional spaces, the idea of *component-wise* is... non-existing.

Comment: @Surb Good point.  While in general, norms give different ideas of the word "distance", in Euclidean space, if $a$ and $b$ are "far apart" in one norm, they will be "far apart" in every norm.

Comment: @user46944 that is one way to think about it.  My take on it is that it is better to think of vector limits in terms of norm rather than in terms of components because the notion of a "normed space" generalizes in a way that the notion of "components" simply doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two formulations are indeed equivalent.  However, you should ask yourself what it means in the first place to say that $\lim_{h \to a}f(h) = L$ when $f:\Bbb R^m \to \Bbb R^n$ and $L \in \Bbb R^n$.

I would claim that *by definition*, this means that $\lim_{h \to a}\|f(h) - L\|_{\Bbb R^n} = 0$, but perhaps you have a different take on things (for example, you might think of things component-wise).  If we look at things the first way, however, the first formulation is a "reminder" of what the second formulation is supposed to mean.